# Extract file using sftp based from a masterlist

Tags: shell, unix

Is it possible to extract certain files based from a master list via sftp.

Example:

directory containts ff files.

```
aa.txt
bb.txt
cc.txt
```

masterlist.txt containts:

```
aa.txt
bb.txt
```

Files that should be extracted

```
aa.txt
bb.txt
```

Edit:

Thanks @shellter for your feedback. 
I did try to write my own code but wasn't able to find samples that I could work on(I'm not a unix person btw).

Anyhow, as for your suggestion regarding using while-read-line, I've tried it but I am getting Invalid command error.

```
#!/bin/ksh
file=MasterList.txt

while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "fetching $line"
sftp user@192.168.1.101
cd /data/EP_files/balex
get "$line"
bye
done <"$file"
```

Lastly, if my masterfile containts 10k list of files, is this kind of approach ok performance wise?

Thank you

Comment: welcome to stackOverflow. But contrary to what you seem to believe, S.O. isn't a free coding service. You're expected to attempt to solve your problem with code. When you encounter a problem with you code, then you should post a Q in the form of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Please learn to search S.O. with basic keywords. I know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554843/how-to-improve-this-ftp-shell-function is not the only Q that covers automation of `ftp` files. Search also for `while read line done` for examples for reading your master list and using that for your func. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the entire sequence of SFTP commands - including the individual `get` commands for all files in the input list *up front*, and then invoke `sftp` only *once*, passing the command list via stdin (standard input):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

file=MasterList.txt

sftp -b - user@192.168.1.101 <<EOF
cd /data/EP_files/balex
$(sed -n 's/^file_.*/get "&"/p' "$file")
bye
EOF
```

The `<<EOF ... EOF` block is a a so-called [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument), which allows passing multiline strings (optionally with embedded variable references and commands) via stdin.

`sed -n 's/^file_.*/get "&"/p' "$file"` embeds a  `get` command for each filename in `$file` that starts with `file_`, ignoring any other lines (as requested by the OP in a comment).

The above assumes that your `sftp` utility accepts a list of commands in "batch" mode via the `-b` option via stdin (`-`).

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked very well. One question, is there a way to add a pattern in sed? like I only need to extract the files in the list that starts with "file_".

Comment: @user2058738: Please see my update; please try to add such requirements to your question up front in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I tried but it did not exclude the lines that does not start with "file_"

Comment: @user2058738: My bad: I neglected to exclude non-matching lines from the `sed` command - please see my update, which adds `sed` option `-n` - to suppress printing all lines by default - and the `p` flag to the `s` function - which only prints (the modified versions of) lines that start with `file_`.

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed. Thank you very much!